# jacoco.exec is not getting created

Tags: jacoco

I'm using jacocoagent.jar having placed in my app code. But when I restarts the app service not getting the jacoco.exec. Not getting the file even after executing test case using the box where app code is deployed. (provided path of the file in one .conf file).Serv is  Geronim used for

Whether jacoco.exec should get created for the first time? once the app service is restarted or once any test case is executed?

Comment: Are you attaching jacocoagent.jar and specifying the destination file in some OPTS variable .. n passing this variable while starting your Tomcat/instance which runs your app's .war/etc file?

Answer (score 0):

By default, JaCoCo generates the .exec file after the server is shut down. If you want to change that behavior, you need to listen to the port where JaCoCo is generating the output and pipe it to another file. This change can be done in the configuration and by running a listener to collect the data generated by JaCoCo.